# htaccess | Apache | Best Practice | Wordpress Plugins | Allowoverride

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, bitnami, kubernetes-helm

Since Apache recommends to for best practice and performance to use Allowoverride None.

How should I map certain wordpress plugins (SuperCache, All in one wp-security, better permalinks) to allow them to write to htaccess if I will not have an htaccess file in the root folder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to this directory: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
and find for

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and simply change it to

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: But I want to follow best practice and leave it set to None. You totally mis understood my question!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running WordPress, you must have `AllowOverride` set to `All` in order for the base WordPress to work.

The way to look at it is that Apache is listing the best practices for a safe base Apache installation for any kind of website.  However, if you have a reason to do something such as turn on AllowOverride to allow WordPress and plugins to work, then that is OK. It is on for a purpose.